# CSV и матрица. Python

Tags: python, csv, матрицы, замена

Есть 3 файла с кодами, главный файл производит команды, которые меняет матрицу(заменяет все значения матрицы на 0) внутри файла csv и записывает её в новый csv файл. Но мне нужно поменять, чтобы второй файл менял первую и последнюю строчку матрицы местами, а не заменял их на 0. Я никак не могу додуматься как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста
Главный файл:

```
import matrixfile as mf
import matrixziro as mz
from matplotlib.pyplot import matshow, show

mzr = mz.GetZiroMatrix(mf.GetMatrix('tekst.csv')) 
mf.SaveMatrix(mzr, 'resultat_2.csv')

matshow(mzr)
show()
```

Второй файл название matrixziro.py, в нём  не получается сделать замену

```
def GetZiroMatrix(mt):
    return [len(m) - 1], m[0] = m[0],len(m) - 1]* len(row) for row in mt] #не работающая функция,оператор должен остаться обязательно
```

третий файл matrixfile.py

```
import csv

def GetMatrix(filename):
    return [[int(token) for token in line.split()] for line in open(filename)]

def SaveMatrix(mt, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for row in mt:
            print(' '.join(map(repr, row)), file=f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def GetMatrix(filename, skip_last_n_rows=4):
    return [[int(token) for token in line.split()] for line in open(filename)][:-skip_last_n_rows]
```